# Edittext as Search in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with the search bar using edittext in the list view. when i type the data, the index is the one that is being thrown not the data itself. What could be the problem. Here is my code:

```
package com.apps.mangkepwengslab;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class SearchListActivity extends Activity {

// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
//    Object obj;
// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;


// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_list);
    onSearchRequested();
    // Listview Data
    String[] commonName =
            {
            "Acacia",
            "Alfalfa",
            "Althea",
            "Anise",
            "Annatto",
            "Antidysenteric Holarrhena",   
            "Arjuna Myrobalan",
            "Artichoke",
            "Asparagus",
            "Avocado",
            "Bael Tree",
            "Balloon Vine",
            "Bamboo",
            "Banana",
            "Basil",
            "Bauhinia",
            "Beetroot",
            "Bengal Currants",
            "Betel Nut Palm",
            "Bilimbi",
            "Bitter Gourd",
            "Black Mulberry",
            "Black Oil Plant",
            "Black Pepper",
            "Brazil Wood",
            "Bread Fruit",
            "Broad Bean",
            "Broccoli",
            "Butter Tree",
            "Cabbage",
            "Cacao",
            "Cactus",
            "Camphor",
            "Carambola",
            "Carrot",
            "Cashew",
            "Castor Bean",
            "Catechu Tree",
            "Celery",
            "Century Plant",
            "Chives",
            "Cinnamon",
            "Clitoria",
            "Clove Tree",
            "Cluster Fig",
            "Coconut",
            "Coffee",
            "Coriander",
            "Corn",
            "Cotton",
            "Country Borage",
            "Cowhage",
            "Creat",
            "Crown Plant",
            "Cucumber",
            "Curry Leaf",
            "Custard Apple",
            "Cypress",
            "Deadly Nightshade",
            "Dodder",
            "Dwarf Nasturtium",
            "Eggplant",
            "Elephant Creeper",
            "Emblic Myrobalan",
            "Eucalyptus",

            "Flame of the Forest",
            "Four Angled Bean",
            "Four OClock Plant",
            "French Beans",
            "Garlic",
            "Ginger",
            "Golden Trumpet",
            "Grape Fruit",
            "Guava",
            "Hibiscus",
            "Hierba Buena",
            "Horse Radish Tree",
            "Hyacinth Bean",
            "Indian Aloe",
            "Indian Privet",
            "Indian Spinach",
            "Ivy Gourd",
            "Jack Tree",
            "Jasmine",
            "Java Plum",
            "Jicama",
            "Kohlrabi",
            "Lantana",
            "Lemon Grass",
            "Lentil",
            "Mandarin Orange",
            "Marigold",
            };

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_items, R.id.product_name, commonName);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)             {
            id  = id + 1 ;
             System.out.println("Text ["+id+"]");
             long new_id = lv.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
            Intent herbIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HerbActivity.class);
 //                Object obj = adapter.getItem(position);
            // Creating a uri to fetch country details corresponding to selected listview item
            Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(HerbContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id));

            // Setting uri to the data on the intent
            herbIntent.setData(data);
   //                countryIntent.setDataAndType(data, "image/jpeg");
            // Open the activity
            startActivity(herbIntent);
        }
    });
    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

             SearchListActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 
 //              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}    
}
```

I Hope that someone may help me. Thanks:)

Comment: question is not clear, what is happening  brother ?

Comment: Rajesh CP. when I do search, it is not the object that being get but the index. For example I search for banana. And i clicked on it. Instead of showing information about banana, it will show the information about acacia, since it is in the first index.

Answer (score 0):

Its may be due the the id getting as response..As after filter the position of Banana will be 0.. So instead of taking id use view and get text from item.Please try..